# How to convert No of days to Hours in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, datetime-conversion

I have a Age.xlsx where I am calculating the age of incidents in no of Days(Granular level I have to found Age in Hours) I am stuck with a situation, I have to calculate no of days with below two conditions.

1. If the completion date is given then **No of days= Completed date-submit date**
2. If the Completed date is NaT(Or blank)(If incident still open then **No of days=L1+L2**

Additionally, How can I convert days to hours eg. "2 days 08:00:00" to "56 hours"?

Sample data:

```
    Incident    Status      Priority    Team    Submit Date          Completed Date     L1  L2  No_of_days Age_in_Hours
    INC0011     Pending     Medium      L2      2020-06-04 00:00:00                     1   1             
    INC0012     completed   High        L2      2020-06-04 00:00:00 2020-06-08 02:00:00 2   2      
    INC0013     In progress Low L1              2020-06-05 00:00:00                     1   2      
    INC0014     Assigned    Medium      L1      2020-06-05 00:00:00                     1   3      
    INC0015     completed   High        L2      2020-06-05 00:00:00 2020-06-05 01:00:00 0   1
```

Sampel code:

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:\Age.xlsx')
x=(data['Completed Date']- data['Submit Date'])
```

Comment: if it's a TimeDelta, you could always to td.total_seconds() / 3600 to get hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask based on whether or not the completed date column is filled, and use `loc` to conditionally fill the number of days column:

- if there is a completion date, take completion date minus start date
- it not, take the sum of `L1` and `L2` and make a `pandas.Timedelta` for that many days

This will make the `"No_of_days"` column be all `Timedelta`, which you can then easily convert to hours by division:

```
#mask is where "Completed Date" is null
mask = df['Completed Date'].isnull()

df.loc[~mask, 'No_of_days'] = df['Completed Date'][~mask] - df['Submit Date'][~mask]
df.loc[mask, 'No_of_days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['L1'][mask] + df['L2'][mask], unit='days')

df['Age_in_Hours'] = df['No_of_days']/pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

Note that there is a difference in precision between times with completed dates and times without (as the `L1` and `L2` are not providing hours).

Answer (score 0):

Answers follow below:

a) If the completion date is given then No of days= Completed date-submit date

```
df['No_of_days'] = df['Completed Date'] - df['Submit Date']
```

b) Additionally, How can I convert days to hours eg. "2 days 08:00:00" to "56 hours"?

```
df['hours'] = df['No_of_days'] / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
```

c) If the Completed date is NaT(Or blank)(If incident still open then No of days=L1+L2 (*Hours is easier than date.*)

The easiest way I have found around this was to use `np.where`, which is basically an `if` statement for arrays. You can check a better explanation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np
df['hours'] = np.where(df['hours'].isnull(), df['L1'] + df['L2'], df['hours'])
```